# Row 2 is out of range (2 - 1) laravel-excel

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpexcel, phpexcelreader, laravel-excel

I am trying to import an excel file using laravel-excel so I used this algorithm

```
$result = Excel::load('public/uploads/test.xlsx',function($reader){

})->get();
```

but I get the following error :
PHPExcel_Exception in RowIterator.php line 125:
**Row 2 is out of range (2 - 1)**

Comment: Solved , I deleted the other sheets on excel and its works :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think i'm getting too late to answer. Though author gets solved by deleting extra sheets. There is an option with package where you can select specific sheet to read.

```
$result = Excel::selectSheets('Sheet1')->load('public/uploads/test.xlsx',function($reader){

})->get();
```

For more details check http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import
for **Selecting sheets and columns**

Hope this may Help !

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution.

```
$results = Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($currentPath)->get();
```

You can select sheet by index number.